# PHP not empty and compare elegant

Tags: php, variables, coding-style

Just wondering if there is an easy way to check if a post variable is not empty and compare with x could put that in a function or use and but i more looking for a elegant way.

```
if( !empty( $_POST['ccc-form-login'] ) )
if( $_POST['ccc-form-login'] == 1 )
{
  //code
}
```

Comment: i find a way but i don't now if it is legal ;)
if( @$_POST['ccc-form-login'] == 1 )
{
  //code
}

Comment: No, it's not  the right way.

Comment: Don't do it. All your doing is dropping the error level down to 0 for that line and asking for trouble down the road. Not to mention @ causes a big performance hit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this

```
if( isset($_POST['ccc-form-login']) ) {
    // it's set and not empty
}
```

But, if you want to check `isset` and `value == 1` then try this

```
if( isset($_POST['ccc-form-login']) && $_POST['ccc-form-login'] == 1 ) {
    // it's set and not empty (value is 1)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!empty($_POST['ccc-form-login'] && $_POST['ccc-form-login'] == 1){
     //something
}
```

That would be about the simplest you could get.

Comment: @RecoveringSince2003 Empty returns true on unset variables EDIT: This comment made more sense before Recovery deleted the first comment